# Is it possible to convert an expression to a string in Lua?

Tags: string, lua

I'm assuming this isn't possible, but I'm just wondering if you could convert an expression to a string.

For example, the following adds five and five together

```
print(tostring(5 + 5)) --> 10
```

I was wondering if you could do something along the lines of the following.

```
print(tostring(5 + 5)) --> 5 + 5
```

I'm wondering because I'm making a graphing calculator, and to create a function, it has to be a string.  I was hoping I could make it more user-friendly by making it so you can just input an expression such as `x ^ 2` instead of `"x ^ 2"`

Comment: Your input reader is almost certainly getting a string... unless you are feeding it a raw lua file directly and having lua parse it as lua code. You can't do what you want *in lua* but you don't need to use the lua parser to handle input either.

Comment: The input isn't taken in using io.read().  They're actually in the lua file.

Comment: So you are using lua itself to parse the file with your expressions? Then, you can't do that. You could use something like metalua or your own parser though.

Comment: I think you might be looking for the wrong solution, or wrong approach. Can you clarify what you are trying to do, like give an example of file with content etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is convert an expression `5 + 5` to a string `"5 + 5"`.

AFAIK, you can't do that in Lua. However, you can do the opposite by transforming `"5 + 5"` to `5 + 5` using `loadstring`. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the expression as part of some Lua code, you can parse that code into something like Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and then convert that AST into whatever structure you need, which may be a string or a function (this may be more convenient for your graphing calculator).

There are several Lua parsers that can do this (both converting Lua code into AST and generating Lua code from AST); both Metalua (5.1 only? bytecode generation only?) and TypedLua (5.2+) can do that and there are some other Lua parsers listed [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaGrammar).